# Memory profiler for Google cloud function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, memory-leaks, google-cloud-functions

I'm running a Google cloud function and getting out-of-memory error:

`Error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted.`

However, when I profile it locally, it doesn't use more than 500-600Mb (My gcf memory allocation is 2Gb)

Is there a way to have a line-by-line profiler to

a) to see which steps result in highest memory increases, and

b) view current memory usage of the cloud function?

Comment: Are you writing files to /tmp? It may explain memory usage, as per doc https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system

Comment: No, i'm not writing anything to `/tmp` explicitly. The function fails on sklearn `fit_predict`, could sklearn use `/tmp` under the hood? I've looked through the source code and it doesn't seem so.

Comment: why on earth does writing to disk consume RAM?!

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely what [Stackdriver Profiler](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/) is for, however Python support is currently "Planned".

Comment: I couldn't find Cloud functions in there, only AppEngine. Where have you seen them?

Comment: You may try Stackimpact.com, for CPU, Memory and Runtime profiling.