# Google Cloud Function out of memory error not making sense

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, out-of-memory

### Question:

Do you know a way to actually monitor how much memory is being used by a GCF (Node.js 8) ?
Do you have recommendations regarding the memory profiling of Google Cloud Functions (even locally) for Node.js 8?

### Context:

I deployed a Google Cloud Function (NodeJS), with 128MB of memory, that used to work pretty well.

Today, it fails saying "`Error: memory limit exceeded.`".

GCP tells me the function doesn't use up more than 58MiB, yet it fails with a memory error when it has 128MB.

I feel lost and flawed because:

1. It used to work and I didn't change a thing since then.
2. It seems I can't trust google when it comes to monitoring the consumption of memory
3. The "Details" screen of the function shows it consuming no more than 58MiB.
   [image: "Details" screen of the function]
4. The Dashboard I created in [Monitoring](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring) in order to monitor it shows the same values.
   [image: Screenshot from the dashboard]
5. Yet it fails with a memory limit.
   [image: Logs of the function]

I have already seen this question [Memory profiler for Google cloud function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952660/memory-profiler-for-google-cloud-function), but Stackdriver Profiler doesn't seem to work for GCF ([per doc](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/about-profiler#environment_and_languages))

Comment: Hi Micka, any chance did you get any clarification on this question? I also have the similar  doubt and could not find a concrete answer.

Answer (score 4):

The cloud functions need to respond when they're done! if they don't respond then their allocated resources won't be free. Any exception in the cloud functions may cause a memory limit error. So you need to handle all corner cases, exceptions, and promise rejections properly and respond immediately!
A [tutorial video series on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLm9A9rcHb1IkyQUu6QwbjdM) by Doug Stevenson.
Another [video about promises in cloud function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9GrysWH1Lc) by Doug.
An [ask firebase video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLjMGTV8vKo) hosted by Jen Person about the memory of cloud function.

Answer (score -1):

### Set memory allocation in Cloud Functions from the Google Cloud Console.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation):

> **To set memory allocation and timeout in the Google Cloud Platform Console:**
>
> 1. In the Google Cloud Platform Console, select Cloud Functions from the left menu.
> 2. Select a function by clicking on its name in the functions list.
> 3. Click the Edit icon in the top menu.
> 4. Select a memory allocation from the drop-down menu labeled Memory allocated.
> 5. Click More to display the advanced options, and enter a number of seconds in the Timeout text box.
> 6. Click Save to update the function.

**Things to check for memory leaks (very tricky to troubleshoot):**

- Async-await functions.
- Promises run "in the background" (with .then).
- [Writing to the writeable part of the filesystem](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system) `/tmp`/ to store temporary files in a function instance will also consume memory provisioned for the function.

### Cloud Function's [Auto-scaling and Concurrency concepts](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#auto-scaling_and_concurrency)

> Each instance of a function handles only one concurrent request at a time. This means that while your code is processing one request, there is no possibility of a second request being routed to the same instance. Thus the original request can use the full amount of resources (CPU and memory) that you requested.

### Cloud Functions monitoring

These are the available resources at hand to monitor your Cloud Functions:

- [Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging) captures and stores Cloud Functions logs.
- [Stackdriver Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/error-reporting) captures specially formatted error logs and displays them in the Error Reporting dashboard.
- [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/metrics) records metrics regarding the execution of Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the point to add more memory, but it is a dirty fix. Especially when my function doesn't consume more than 64MiB as shown. However I didn't know about `Stackdriver Monitoring`, I wonder if it will displays different numbers than the ones Google already shows.

Comment: Are you writing to `/tmp` by any chance? Look at this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58819497/error-memory-limit-exceeded-when-17-21-is-used-according-to-psutils). I'm not saying that it will be the exact same issue but can clearly show you ways to debug your code and figure out what is making the memory increase.